# jquery each selector doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I created a counter that count different numbers each, but when I choose all the elemnts in class it doesnt work...

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    function change() {
        /*
        $(".test").each(function(i,domeElement){

            var theNum = parseInt(this.html())+1;
            this.html(theNum);
        });
        */

        //this works... the other one doesnt why?!?!
        var theNum = parseInt($(".test").html()) + 1;
        $(".test").html(theNum);
    }

    setInterval(change, 1000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DTyY7/

Comment: Please don't *just* link to JSFiddle in your question; always include the code in the the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
$(this).html(theNum);
```

and not

```
this.html(theNum);
```

Because `html()` is a jQuery function and `this`  (inside `.each()`) is a domElement and so you must wrap it into a jQuery object

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/DTyY7/2/

Comment: wasted 3 hours only for that :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your `each()` callback body should be changed to `$(this)`:

```
$(".test").each(function(){
    var theNum = parseInt($(this).html())+1 || 0;
    $(this).html(theNum);
});
```

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7rrTf/) demo.

Answer (score 0):

it is applying the first instance of `.test` to all of them. You need to loop through all of the elements and apply a `+1` separately.

```
$('.test').each(function(){
           $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html())+1)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function change() {
        $(".test").each(function(i,domeElement) {
            var theNum = parseInt($(this).html())+1;
            $(this).html(theNum);
        });
    }
    setInterval(change,1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $(this) instead this .I have updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/DTyY7/6/ .Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


function change(){

    $(".test").each(function(i, domElement){

        //var theNum = parseInt(this.html())+1;
        var num = parseInt($(".test").html());
        num++
        $(".test").html(num);
    });


    //this works... the other one doesnt why?!?!
      /* var theNum = parseInt($(".test").html())+1;
        $(".test").html(theNum);
*/}

setInterval(change,1000);
```

});

This is how you can fix it. Because you are in another scope the keword this doesn't work.