# Jquery selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {  
    alert("Hello!");  
});  
$(".demo").click(function() {  
    alert("I am demo");  
});  
</script>  
<body>  
    <button class="demo">click me</button>  
</body>
```

The first Hello! is OK, but I am demo can't?What's the matter?

the similar question
[jquery each selector doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490290/jquery-each-selector-doesnt-work)

Comment: You need to bind the event handler in the dom ready callback function.

Comment: From the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Hello_jQuery): *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."* ... it's worth a read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your click event handler is trying to bind to the `demo` button before the HTML body has rendered. You need to assign the event handler inside your `$(document).ready` function:

Change this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    alert("Hello!");  
});  
$(".demo").click(function() {  
    alert("I am demo");  
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    alert("Hello!");  
    $(".demo").click(function() {  
        alert("I am demo");  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the click event inside `ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    alert("Hello!"); 
    $(".demo").click(function() {  
        alert("I am demo");  
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DFdXz/)

```
 $(".demo").live('click',function() {  
        alert("I am demo");  
    });​
```